# Issue with scrollToRowAtIndexPath in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a really simple question, but I can't figure out the issue.

I am trying to add a navigation bar button on a UITableView which scrolls the user to a specific row. I thought it would be simple using the below code:

```
@IBAction func scrollToNow(sender: AnyObject) {
    careerTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(4, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: true)
}
```

But I am currently getting the error:

```
Cannot invoke 'scrollToRowAtIndexPath' with an argument list of type '(Int, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the name of the method. The first argument is an indexPath not an Int. Pass an indexPath, and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func scrollToNow(sender: AnyObject) {
    careerTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(index: 4), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: true)
}
```